# My industry is suddenly abandoning buildings due to a lack of workers

Tags: cities-skylines

Rather suddenly my industrial district started to look like this, with a lot of buildings abandoned:

[image]

If I check the buildings, the stated reason for abandoning is a lack of workers. I looked at the city statistics, but I can't see any reason for the sudden lack of workers:

[image]

The number of jobs is stable, the population increased. This doesn't make any sense to me. Any idea what causes this and how to fix the situations?

Answer (score 11):

Has your city's overall education level increased recently? Low level industrial buildings want uneducated workers, and workers will prefer to take jobs that are of their education level. Your workforce may be over-educated now and avoiding industrial jobs.

If this is the case, the only way I know to deal with this short of shuttering all of your schools is to keep a close equilibrium between workers and jobs. Educated workers will take lower education jobs if there's nothing else available, so having a shortage of jobs at their level will force them in.

Once you've done that, start working on raising the level of the factories themselves. Higher level industry takes higher level workers and will be much happier in your city with its educated work force. You can do this by adding services to the industrial area like fire departments and transportation (particularly freight trains).

Comment: Someone had good tips on setting up a district of people to work factories, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/210367/how-to-you-use-districts-efficiently

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps, but I always link Industrial areas with Residential areas using public transport, on the premise that people need to get to work.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of a few reasons reasons:

1.- one abandoned building will cause the area around it to be less appealing. which can lead to more abandoned buildings. Make sure you destroy abandoned buildings when you see one.

2.- people who work there are not able to get there anymore, this may happen if you remove a road, and no one is able to get to the building. Double check your roads.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running into this issue with specialized industry (agriculture, forest industry), consider adding or re-zoning high-density residential zones within the district and assign the "Highrise Ban" and "High Density Residential Tax-Relief" policies. This would be a short-term fix as you'll see a huge influx of uneducated young adults, but this may change over time as they get educated. This is especially true if any education buildings are nearby.

Answer (score 1):

As to what Luisluix said that can be one of the problems but another major one is the industry trucks that carry the goods cannot get to there location, If you have a larger city or different segments here and there then you need to get the trucks to a easy access highway to deliver the goods and in return make you and the company money. Without them transporting the goods you do not make money from it and the company goes broke and in turn goes abandoned.